# Raising a letter of credit

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, business-language

What does *raise* mean in the following sentence?

> The Letter of Credit to be **raised** as soon as possible after the Contract signature.

Does it mean collecting the money? Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just another way of saying that the letter of credit is to be drawn up and issued.

Comment: @livresque. I'm not sure I understand your comment, but, just to be clear, letters of credit have nothing to do with credit cards.